# Rally App SDK 2.0: Callback function after all cards have loaded/rendered on Kanban Board

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, rally

I need to run a function specifically after all the cards have been loaded/rendered. However, I don't see any means for a callback of this sort, so I am not entirely sure how this could be done.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean the Kanban app or the Cardboard component?

For the Cardboard component, there is the [load](https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p3/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.cardboard.CardBoard-event-load) event which fires when the cardboard has fully loaded everything.

```
Ext.create({
     xtype: 'rallycardboard',
     types: ['User Story'],
     attribute: 'ScheduleState',
     listeners: {
        load: function() {
              // cardboard is done loading
        }
     }
});
```

Comment: Does this include all the cards? Or just the base cardboard/columns?

Comment: It includes all the cards. Each column fires a `ready` event when all of their cards have loaded, the cardboard listens to these events and fires `load` when all of the columns have reported they are ready.